# Count occurrences of cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet with a single column of 15,000 integers. Each integer represents a date, in the format YYYYMMDD. The dates are limited to a 90-day period. I want to calculate the frequency with which each date appears in the list.

How can I get the frequency of occurrence of all values in the column?

Comment: Looks like you have not done any research on Google. This is the first result on top of the list http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-how-often-a-value-occurs-HP001127779.aspx#BMcount_how_often_a_single_value_occurs

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! I recommend you take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - and head back when you have a specific programming-related question.

Comment: @FeliceM I did a Google search first and I tried using the countif formula but I have 90 unique dates to get a count of. That didn't seem to allow for a wildcard or a date range

Comment: In any case you need 90 formulas to get the count of each date

Comment: Glad you've received a solution from Franz. Next time, this question would be more suitable for SuperUser, another StackExchange site. I've recommended it be moved there for posterity. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Pivot Tables and Charts.

1. Select the column that contains the data. Make sure that the column has a column heading.
2. On the Insert tab, in the Tables group, click PivotTable.

   [image: spreadsheet]
3. The Create PivotTable dialog box is displayed.
4. Click Select a table or range.
5. Place the PivotTable report in a new worksheet starting at cell A1 by clicking New Worksheet.
6. Click OK.
7. An empty PivotTable report is added to the location that you specified with the PivotTable field list displayed.
8. In the field section at the top of the PivotTable field list, click and hold the field name, and then drag the field to the Row Labels box in the layout section at the bottom of the PivotTable field list.
9. In the field section at the top of the PivotTable field list, click and hold the same field name, and then drag the field again to the Values box in the layout section at the bottom of the PivotTable Field List.

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/count-how-often-a-value-occurs-HP010070480.aspx#BMcount_how_often_multiple_values_occur) is the related article from microsoft.

Comment: I have just come to the same conclusion and will start to research creating a pivot table.